# Laravel append rules on custom validation rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

In request I got attribute that defines validation rules and flow. Let's say it is account_type: business, personal. 
Each value changes validation flow and requires different attributes to be present ir request.

Let's say I have following custom rules methods:

```
public function validateAccountTypeBusiness($attribute, $value, $parameters, Validator $validator)
{
   // check is present:
   // Company address
   // VAT number
}

public function validateAccountTypePersonal($attribute, $value, $parameters, Validator $validator)
{
   // check is present:
   // User mobile phone
}
```

Since each rule requires more than single attribute to be presented in this request depending on account type ( vat number, company name, etc ) returning `false` would be not informative to user because generated response notices that account type is invalid without any details which actual attributes is missing.

The question is: how I can append more rules to be validated in this validation custom rule?

Following not working:

```
public function validateAccountTypeBusiness($attribute, $value, $parameters, Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->addRules([
        'company_address'   =>  'required|string',
        'vat_number'        =>  'required',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you consider using Conditionally Adding Rules: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules ?

Answer (score 4):

If you follow [Complex Conditional Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules), you can validate using the following way

**Step 1:** Create Validator instance with static rules which would be same in both the cases(business or personal account) like name,check,phone,email,etc.

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'name' => 'required|alpha',
    'phone' => 'required|numeric',
    'check' => 'required' //common in both account type
    //add more rules as required
]);
```

**Step 2:** Add specific rules with condition

```
$v->sometimes('VAT', 'required|max:50', function ($input) {
    return $input->account_type == 'business';
});

$v->sometimes('Company_address', 'required|max:500|alpha', function ($input) {
    return $input->account_type == 'business';
});

$v->sometimes('user_mobile', 'required|numeric', function ($input) {
    return $input->account_type == 'personal';
});
```

Parameters for `sometimes()` method :

> The first argument passed to the sometimes method is the name of the
>   field we are conditionally validating. The second argument is the
>   rules we want to add. If the Closure passed as the third argument
>   returns true, the rules will be added.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Custom validation rule can be used for only one parameter & you're trying to club them together.

This is one of many ways to approach your problem. Hope it helps.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new user account.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->input('account_type' == 'business') {
          // Validation for business account
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'company_address' => 'required|string',
                'vat_number' => 'required',
            ]);
        }
        else {
         // Validation for personal account
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'contact_number' => 'required',
            ]);
        }

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('account/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the user account...
    }
}
```

Reference -

Manually creating validators -
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators